# simple script to backup PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, database-backups

Hello I write simple batch script to backup postgeSQL databases, but I find one strange problem whether the **pg_dump** command can specify a password?

There is batch script:

```
 REM script to backup PostgresSQL databases
 @ECHO off

 FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i IN ("%date%") DO (

 SET dow=%%i
 SET month=%%j
 SET day=%%k
 SET year=%%l
 )

 SET datestr=%month%_%day%_%year%
 SET db1=opennms
 SET db2=postgres
 SET db3=sr_preproduction
 REM SET db4=sr_production

 ECHO datestr is %datestr%

 SET BACKUP_FILE1=D:\%db1%_%datestr%.sql
 SET FIlLENAME1=%db1%_%datestr%.sql

 SET BACKUP_FILE2=D:\%db2%_%datestr%.sql
 SET FIlLENAME2=%db2%_%datestr%.sql

 SET BACKUP_FILE3=D:\%db3%_%datestr%.sql
 SET FIlLENAME3=%db3%_%datestr%.sql

 SET BACKUP_FILE4=D:\%db14%_%datestr%.sql
 SET FIlLENAME4=%db4%_%datestr%.sql

 ECHO Backup file name is %FIlLENAME1% , %FIlLENAME2% , %FIlLENAME3% , %FIlLENAME4%

 ECHO off
 pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 %db1%  > %BACKUP_FILE1%
 pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 %db2%  > %BACKUP_FILE2%
 pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 %db3%  > %BACKUP_FILE3%
 REM pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 %db4%  > %BACKUP_FILE4%

 ECHO DONE !
```

Please give me advice

Regards Mick

Answer (score 2):

**edited** to reflect information in comments

There is no option to feed the password form command line. You need to include the `-w` or `--no-password` switch and create a file that will contain the password for the connection. It is a text file in the form

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

By default this file will be readed from  `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`, but its location can be changed setting the environment variable `PGPASSFILE` to the path to the file to use.

You can find more information in the [product documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: Or set the [`PGPASSWORD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) environment variable.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev, of course, you are right. It is just that i don't like the `Use of this environment variable is not recommended` in the documentation you link.

Comment: or set the `PGPASSFILE` shell/environment variable.

Comment: @wildplasser, i forget to include that, answer updated. Thank you